# How to find the ten largest files in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-management

How can I find the ten largest files on the D: drive in Windows 7?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The following in PowerShell should suffice:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse D:\ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Sort -Descending Length |
    Select -First 10
```

or shorter:

```
gci -r D:\ -ea 0 | sort Length -desc | select -f 10
```

Comment: Side note: I explicitly set `ErrorAction` for the `Get-ChildItem` so that any errors due to insufficient rights are suppressed. Otherwise there'd be a bunch of red lines before the actual output. Still, I think it nicely shows how easy to use PowerShell can be :-)

Answer (score 17):

[Try WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/)

> WinDirStat reads the whole directory
>   tree once and then presents it in
>   three useful views:
>
> - The directory list, which resembles the tree view of the Windows Explorer
>     but is sorted by file/subtree size,
> - The treemap, which shows the whole contents of the directory tree
>     straight away,
> - The extension list, which serves as a legend and shows statistics about
>     the file types.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/) Works a lot like WinDirStat, but presents a friendlier pie chart.  It also supports listing the "Top 100" in several categories, including size.  The only caveat is that it requires Java, but if you already have Java, I really recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

[SequoiaView](http://w3.win.tue.nl/nl/onderzoek/onderzoek_informatica/visualization/sequoiaview/) can also provide the same functionality as WinDirStat.

Answer (score 1):

A less graphic tool is "[TreeSize Free](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/)":

[image: TreeSize Free Screenshot]

It's bigger brother, "[TreeSize Professional](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/)", can however do graphics:

[image: TreeSize Professional Screenshot]

Comment: I've used this before. It's very efficient...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the FREE [Folder Size](http://www.mindgems.com/products/Folder-Size/Folder-Size.html) by MindGems. It provides even better results than the commercial tools listed above and is not cluttered with nonsense data. The most important things for me are the accurate results that it provides, while I can not say that for other similar tools.