# Where should I insert this code?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, code

I can't understand where to insert this code (from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/156035)) to run it and find the ten largest files on the D drive:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse D:\ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Sort -Descending Length |
    Select -First 10
```

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: There is clearly not enough information here. For what? What are you trying to accomplish? You need to edit your question and add more detail, otherwise the question will be closed.

Comment: Perhaps you should’ve read the complete answer, then. You also might want to provide a link to the answer in question. Or tell us what you’re trying to do in the first place.

Comment: For anyone who is curious: This particular command lists the 10 largest files on the D: drive.

Answer (score 2):

That's a [PowerShell](https://superuser.com/tags/powershell/info) command. You can run PowerShell by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the Run dialog, typing `powershell`, and pressing Enter. Alternatively, you can search for `powershell` in the Start menu and select Windows PowerShell. To run commands, type or paste them at the prompt and press Enter. Once the command completes (which might take a while if your directory structure has a lot of items), a handful of files' information will be printed to the console. Note that if you want to list the largest files in some folder hierarchy other than `D:\`, you should change the first line to point to your desired target folder.